# Image format of Android screen shot taken via commandline

Tags: android, linux, image, image-processing, android-ndk

Recently i got a way to display data onto the frame buffer via the adb shell command line. To fetch data from the frame buffer i used the command :

**cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /sdcard/screenshot**

Now in my /sdcard i got a raw image screenshot. Inorder to display this on the frame buffer that is the device screen, i used the command :

**cat /sdcard/screenshot > /dev/graphics/fb0**

As an output i could see the screen shot on my device screen( Note: My device is rooted so i can access /dev/graphics/fb0).

Now my problem is: I have to display  an image which is RGB888 format on the screen from the command line. So i tried :

**cat /sdcard/rgbimg > /dev/graphics/fb0**

But as an output on the screen i can see a white and black dots instead of the image.

So inorder to display my RGB888 on the frame buffer i need to convert it to the format in which the file screen shot is. Hence if anyone has tried than can you tell me the format of the image screenshot in my above example.

Any suggestions regarding how to get the format of this will also be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /sdcard/screenshot

This command produced a file which is RGBA, red green blue alpha. At least I'm assume it is an alpha channel, every byte I get has an FF in the 4th byte position.

I was able to get the raw file to open in photoshop using a raw file open 4 channel 544x1920 interleaved, which displayed 2 copies of the screen, one over top of the other. I'm not sure why there are 2 copies, maybe double buffer? Maybe internal/external video?

To see the raw file as an RGB, i copies the yellow channel to the red, the green to the green and the cyan to the blue channels and the image looks just like the image captured from the DDMS screen capture button, except for having a stack of 2 images rather than just one.

Answer (score 2):

Image on screen is probably 32 bpp ([bits per pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth)). Just check the file size of captured image and divide it by `(width * height)`. That should tell you for sure how many bytes a pixel uses.

If it is 4 bytes, you need to convert your RGB888 image to ARGB or RGBA. Afaik difference on alpha bytes position depends on display hardware, not Android.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is the tool to do this kind of work. For example, you can convert a RGBA image to a `png` by

```
convert -size 'width'x'height' -depth 8 filename.rgba filename.png
```

more concrete example would be

```
convert -size 680x1209 -depth 8 phone_decor.rgba phone_decor.png
```

Since raw data for your image doesn't include width, height, depth information you need to provide these.

Please see [convert's manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) to find more about image conversion options (I should admit it is not the best manual I've seen).

Answer (score 1):

This is device dependant but most probably you need RGBA. The raw image you obtained from the framebuffer also constains more than one copies (you can calculate how many by inspecting the file size).

You can try this script to generate an image with color bars in `fb.raw` you can then copy to `/dev/graphics/fb0` (adapt W, H and c to your hardware):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

W=480
H=800

# R G B
COLORS = [
    "\xff\x00\x00",
    "\x00\xff\x00",
    "\x00\x00\xff",
    "\xff\xff\x00",
    "\x00\xff\xff",
    "\xff\x00\xff",
    ]
ALPHA = "\xff"
BLACK = "\x00\x00\x00\xff"
N = len(COLORS)

def color(x):
    for i in range(N):
        if x <= (i+1)*W/N:
            return COLORS[i]

f = open('fb.raw', 'wb')

for c in range(2):
    for y in range(H):
        if c == 0:
            for x in range(W):
                f.write(color(x)+ALPHA)
        else:
             f.write(BLACK)

f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. +1 for your efforts. I think this is python script. I'll try it out..

Comment: The "copies" of the framebuffer, or the double-framebuffer, thus usually 2.

Comment: Hey thanks... Seems like your code worked... Just wanted to confirm if the output is colourful bars???? Also in linux if i want to view this generated fb.raw, then which tool shall i use??

Comment: Can you please tell me. what is the value of "A" in RGBA. Is it constant for all ALPHA or it varies?? Pls help

Comment: The output should be vertical bars if everything works fine. ALPHA is transparency, you can set any value from \x00 to \xff.

Comment: +1 to you... One last thing i have an RGB buffer in order to change it to RGBA Should i only set a value between x0 and xff for the Alpha part of the new rgba buffer???

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that the default camera output format is NV21, I guess it could be the format used for the display (this would seem logic to output from the camera a format that can be displayed as-is).

If this can be of any help, the various image formats supported by Android are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html), and the format you're looking for is probably one of these. The implementation details of these formats can be found [here](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php) for example!

Hope this helps.