# If I issue 'adb shell screencap /storage/sdcard/file. What type of file the result is?

Tags: android, adb

In adb shell, screencap -h tell me:

```
usage: screencap [-hp] [-d display-id] [FILENAME]  
    -h: this message  
    -p: save the file as a png.  
    -d: specify the display id to capture, default 0.  
If FILENAME ends with .png it will be saved as a png.  
If FILENAME is not given, the results will be printed to stdout.
```

It doesn't indicate what type of file the captured screen is.

Comment: What do you mean by type? What type are you expecting? `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4` will save the video in `mp4`  format.

Comment: @java_dude There is a difference between `screencap` and `screenrecord`.

Comment: @still_learning Of course there is a difference. I just added it as an example to show file name extension `mp4`.

Comment: still_learning's answer is correct, however I noticed that the 12 byte header information is in little endian format. Maybe this is actually a known fact which I didn't know about. Anyway, hope this helps someone who didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the message you posted *does* indicate something about the format: You can get a PNG file using the `-p` flag.

You find find the source of screencap [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp). Apparently, `screencap` saves the data in a raw format (unless you tell it to save it as PNG).

You can find more information about the format in the source code:

1. It seems to start with a 12 byte header:

   1. Width (4 bytes)
   2. Height (4 bytes)
   3. Pixel format (4 bytes). The available formats are listed [in this file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-mr1-dev/include/ui/PixelFormat.h):

      PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888   = HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888,  // 4x8-bit RGBA
      PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBX_8888   = HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBX_8888,  // 4x8-bit RGB0
      PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_888     = HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_888,    // 3x8-bit RGB
      PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565     = HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565,    // 16-bit RGB
      PIXEL_FORMAT_BGRA_8888   = HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_BGRA_8888,  // 4x8-bit BGRA
      PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_5551   = HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_5551,  // 16-bit ARGB
      PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_4444   = HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_4444,  // 16-bit ARGB
      PIXEL_FORMAT_A_8         = 8,                           // 8-bit A
2. The main part of the file is basically the in-memory representation of the image. This part has a size of `width * height * bytesPerPixel(pixelFormat)` bytes. The image is saved row by row, so the pixel data at a given screen position starts at the offset `(y * width + x) * bytesPerPixel(pixelFormat)`.

Most pixel formats should be pretty simple to decode. [Other users assume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825872) that the screen buffer will always be `PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888`. Look at the answers of the linked question for instructions on how to convert it into a file - or just use the `-p` option!